# Save each recording on Master from ISD1820 Voice Board

Tags: microprocessors, audio

While looking for a voice recording module, I found ISD1820 to be one of the cheapest and with good SNR. I am just not sure of the fact that whether each recording from it can be saved to the master (here RPi).

If anyone here already have an experience with the module can share as in how to interface the module so as to save each recording which could be later posted to a server in form of `.wav` file by the master.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like maybe a r-pi specific question. I think you'd be better off asking it on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ I'm also not really clear what processing you're expecting from this module.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane if I am using ISD1820 Voice Board for Sound Recording, It says that it has a 20 sec of recording duration which is sufficient in my case. Can you tell me whether I would be able to extract each recording separately?

Comment: You need to update the question. I can't answer this, but I can tell you what is missing in the information you're providing with the question...

Comment: I have edited the question, kindly look into

Answer (score 4):

You can trigger Record and Play from pins described in [1] and printed in board. Audio signal can be saved to .wav with ALSA library [2] and saved to SD card. Then it can be sent as HTTP POST to server.

One issue is that ISD1820 is meant for looping, so you have to manually stop recording when time is 20sec.

[1] 
https://www.elecfreaks.com/wiki/index.php?title=Voice_Record_Module_-_ISD1820

[2] https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15018/sound-recording-program-using-nano